# How to update Go application in Amazon Linux

Tags: go, goofys

I am not familiar with Go. I want to update this application https://github.com/kahing/goofys to the recent version(right now its v0.0.10).
  I tried

```
$ go get github.com/kahing/goofys

$ go install github.com/kahing/goofys
```

But the version does not change. I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run, `-u` is used for update.

```
go get -u github.com/kahing/goofys
```

Then run (optional step, if you see a binary `goofys` in `$GOPATH/bin`; go install is not required. See comments why)

```
go install github.com/kahing/goofys
```

Comment: The install is redundant. `go get` will install the binary if the referenced package is installable.

Comment: @Adrian that's true. Actually `kahing/goofys` requires `go install` otherwise it won't install.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense... If go get won't install it, neither will go install. Is there a different sub package that needs to be installed?

Comment: @Adrian Yep, I had a same doubt then I gave it try; go get didn't produce the binary in the `bin` directory. I have not analyzed the package, may be you can try to analysis.

Comment: `go get` worked fine for me, it installed the binary in the correct location with no additional steps. The `go install` second step is unnecessary. Make sure you're not passing `-d` to `go install`, which causes it not to install the binary.

Comment: I know, I have not passed `-d` argument. It didn't work for me, so I have added that step. Anyway I have update the answer with notes.